How to test a CLI app with Typer and Questionary?
I have created a CLI app using Typer in Python. Among other things, it should be possible to create new records. For querying the individual properties, I have used the Questionary package. The CLI app looks something like this:
@app.command()
def new():
    console.print("Creating new data entry...\n")
    questions = [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "name": "examination",
            "message": "What is the examination name?",
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "name": "examination_date",
            "message": "What is the examination date?",
        }, 
        {
            "type": "text",
            "name": "patient_age",
            "message": "What is the patient age?",
        },
        {
            "type": "select",
            "name": "gender",
            "message": "What is the patient gender?",
            "choices": ["M", "F"],
        },
    ]
    data = prompt(questions)
    data["patient_age"] = int(data["patient_age"])

    examination = service.add(data)

    console.print(f"\nNew data entry was created with ID: {examination.id}")


When I execute the command in the terminal, everything works correctly and the individual queries are made. However, I have a problem when testing the code. I used Typer's CliRunner to simulate the terminal commands.
from typer.testing import CliRunner

import my_package.cli.app as cli


def test_cli_app_without_any_arguments():
    input_text = "".join([
        "Test Name\r",
        "2023-12-21\r",
        "56\r",
        "\r\r"
    ])
    result = CliRunner().invoke(cli.app, ["new"], input=input_text)

    print(result.output) # print to output for better understanding what is going on...

    assert "Creating new data entry..." in result.output
    assert "What is the examination name?" in result.output

Unfortunately, the test fails with an AssertionError, that "Creating new data entry..." is not in result.output. The printed output looks like this:
Creating new data entry...

? What is the examination name?          ? What is the examination name?

Aborted.

Is there a way to test interactions with Questionary in pytest?
